# jQuery: How to fire event when all asynchronous calls return?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, asynchronous

I have a jQuery application that loads data from five asynchronous server calls. I do not want to display any data until all five calls return. (I plan on displaying a Loading message until that happens.)

How can I detect when all five calls have returned? I considered having each callback method increment a variable (using jQuery's data() method, perhaps) and then waiting for the value to become 5. (I am not sure yet how I would listen for that event.) I do not think this is a very good solution, however. What would happen if two calls return at the same time?

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are already using jQuery for the AJAX calls, you can use [`$.ajaxStop()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) for this, it fires when **all** current calls come back, you can use it like this:

```
$("#loading").ajaxStop(function() {
  $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

This isn't really that different than `.click()` in terms that it's just an event, you can use the `ajaxStop` event yourself if you want, like this:

```
$("#loading").bind('ajaxStop', function() {
  $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: Couldn't explain it better! :)

Comment: +1 - Once again you've shown me something I never knew jQuery did. I've been using a counter variable this whole time ..